# How to get ORACLE sqlplus command response time on multiple server using shell script?

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I need to sqlplus command response time to check db connectivity in oracle 12c using shell script.. In order to get db connectivity time from multiple server by sqlplus command response time within 4-5 secs..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SQLPlus, but I'd rather use TNSPING (especially as you're about to call it from operating system command prompt).